# HTMLUnit Java - pretend browser plugins

Tags: java, htmlunit, browser-plugin

I am programming a Java tool that should analyse websites to detect malicious websites.
With malicious websites I mean pages who try to exploit vulnerabilities of the browser or the installed Plug-ins.

But these websites (exploit kits) analyse first the Browser Version and if a particular Plug-in version is installed. After the analyse they inject dynamically 'iframes' into the website with a file/shellcode that can use a vulnerability to infect the PC.
For this reason I would like to pretend to have installed some plugins. With this piece of code I can display which Plugins are "installed".

```
        webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        Set<PluginConfiguration> plugins = webClient.getBrowserVersion().getPlugins();

        Iterator<PluginConfiguration> iterator = plugins.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            PluginConfiguration plug = iterator.next();
            //Console Output
            tr(plug.getName() + "$" + plug.getDescription() );
        }
```

#### Output

*Shockwave Flash$Shockwave Flash 9.0 r31*

Does someone know how I can pretend per example a PDF Plug-in? 
Thanks